# Check if comma exists inside tag

Tags: mysql, regex, mariadb

I want to list all rows that contain a certain tag with multiple attributes. Eg.:

> [TAG=XX, YYY]ljasdljaslkdj[/TAG]

(space is optional)

I've tried this, but it doesn't return any rows:

```
 select * from oldtexts old WHERE old.content REGEXP "^\\[TAG=[A-Za-z][,][A-Za-z]\]" LIMIT 10
```

I only it to return tags with a comma inside (meaning it has attributes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want isn't totally clear. Here's fixing the bad starting escape and allowing more than two parameters, spaces, and several characters per parameter:

```
"^\[TAG=[A-Za-z ]+(,[A-Za-z ]+)+\]"
```